# Adding files via the build server to TFS in a deployment area which is in another location on TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have an application which compiles and runs all okay on our TFS build server.

Now I need to place the files in a deployment area in TFS, as part of the build process on our build server, which is not a workspace that is being used by the build.

I have tried using MSBuild.ExtensionPack.VisualStudio.TfsSource and the Working Directory but this does not work and I need an alternative

Comment: By place the files in a deployment area, do you mean you want to check them into TFS source control or you want to move them to another file share other than the drop location?

Answer (score 0):

We've done something similar by adding an msbuild proj to our source control and then after building our solution, we build this proj which then calls a copy task which moves some files to another folder. Think you can do something similar by editing the default template too (which we didn't want to do)